# Supremum and Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set, $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega})$, $\mathcal{M}$ be a set of probability measure on $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega})$ with $\forall \omega , P(\{\omega\})>0$, and $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$ -algebra on $\Omega$.

I want to prove or disprove that $\displaystyle \sup_{Q\in \mathcal{M}}E^Q[\sup_{Q'\in \mathcal{M}}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]]=\sup_{Q\in\mathcal{M}}E^Q[X]$.

**My Attempt**

By definition, for any $Q\in\mathcal{M}$,

$\sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}] \geq E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]$.

By taking the expectation w.r.t. $Q$ of both sides, we have

$E^{Q}[\sup_{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]] \geq E^Q[E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]]=E^Q[X]$

By taking $\sup$ of both sides,

$\sup_{Q}E^Q[\sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]]\geq\sup_{Q}E^Q[X]$

Now we need to prove the $\leq$ part of the inequality. By definition of sup, we have

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists Q(\epsilon)\in\mathcal{M}$ s. t.$ \sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]\geq E^{Q(\epsilon)}[X|\mathcal{F}]\geq \sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]-\epsilon$

By the squeezing theorem, we have $E^{Q(\epsilon)}[X|\mathcal{F}] \to \sup_{Q}E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}](\epsilon \to 0).$

By taking the expectation w.r.t $Q(\epsilon)$ of $E^{Q(\epsilon)}[X|\mathcal{F}]\geq \sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]-\epsilon$, we have

$E^{Q(\epsilon)}[E^{Q(\epsilon)}[X|\mathcal{F}]]\geq E^{Q(\epsilon)}[\sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]]-\epsilon$.

By using $\sup_{Q}E^{Q}[E^{Q}[X|\mathcal{F}]] \geq E^{Q(\epsilon)}[E^{Q(\epsilon)}[X|\mathcal{F}]]$, we have

$\sup_{Q}E^{Q}[E^{Q}[X|\mathcal{F}]] \geq E^{Q(\epsilon)}[\sup_{Q'}E^{Q'}[X|\mathcal{F}]]-\epsilon$

Now I am stuck here. I wanted to take $\epsilon \to 0$, but what we have is $E^{Q(\epsilon)}[X|\mathcal{F}] \to \sup_{Q}E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}](\epsilon \to 0)$, which is not useful here.

I feel like there is a counterexample but haven't come up with it by now.

Any help? As a reference, here is a definition of conditional expectation I am using.

**Definition of conditional expectation**

Let $\{B_i\}$ be atoms of $\mathcal{F}$, and $P\in \mathcal{M}$. For a random variable $X$, $E[X|\mathcal{F}]:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$E^P[X|\mathcal{F}](\omega) = \frac{E^P[X,B_i]}{P(B_i)}$, where $B_i$ is an atom that has $\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write

$$ S = \sup_{Q} \mathbb{E}^{Q}\biggl[\sup_{Q'}\mathbb{E}^{Q'}[X\mid\mathcal{F}]\biggr] $$

for simplicity. Then we already know that $ S \geq \sup_Q \mathbb{E}^{Q}[X] $, and so, it suffices to prove the reverse inequality.

Now, let $\omega_0 \in \Omega$ be such that $X(\omega_0) = \max X$. We also write $M = \max \lvert X \rvert$. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $Q_{\epsilon} \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $Q_{\epsilon}(\{\omega_0\}) > 1-\epsilon$, and so,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}^{Q_{\epsilon}}[X]
&\geq \mathbb{E}^{Q_{\epsilon}}[X \mathbf{1}_{\{\omega_0\}} - M \mathbf{1}_{\Omega\setminus\{\omega_0\}}] \\
&= X(\omega_0)(1-\epsilon) - M\epsilon \\
&= \max X - (X(\omega_0) + M)\epsilon \\
&\geq S - (X(\omega_0) + M)\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, this proves that

$$ \sup_Q \mathbb{E}^{Q}[X] \geq S $$

and therefore the equality holds. This proof also hints that the supremum is essentially "achieved" at the point mass concentrated at the maximum point of $X$.